# Recovering Firefox cache?

Tags: firefox, browser-cache

How can I recover a page that has expired *from* the Firefox cache?

Long story short, I have a private server at localhost that I run. I had two pages (important essays I wrote) that I basically deleted from my database. The Firefox cache only had one of the two essays; I'm guessing I visited the other page too long ago (though it was only a couple days ago). Is there any way to recover this?

Answer (score 1):

Try going into Firefox offline mode and opening the page.
If it opens, then you're in luck

Comment: Nope, only the page that was in my cache was available.